# Any idea why "npm install gulp --save-dev" would (re)install ALL node modules, and not just gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, homebrew

"npm install gulp --save-dev" creates a "node_modules" folder with a copy of everything I have in ~/node_modules ...and not just gulp, as intended.

Sorry if this is a general node/NPM setup question, and not specific enough to gulp, but I thought I would start here.

FYI I am using a Mac and NPM installed via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Each node package/module come with its own dependencies. This is why you can have various versions of modules used in your project. For example if you have package util, package a and package b, package a can use version 1.2 of util while package b can use version 1.8. This is why each package maintains its own directory of node_modules. Further more, note that sub packages can have more nested node_modules.
Bottom line, this is the normal behavior.

Comment: Sure, but there are two things that point to a misconfiguration perhaps on my end. 1) I'm following a tutorial wherein the same command is run and results with just one folder (gulp) being added to "node_modules" ....and 2) It's an exact copy of all global packages already installed in my home directory. Packages that wouldn't be relevant at all to this specific project. ...isn't the point of "npm install gulp --save-dev" to fetch and install (just) the gulp package?

Comment: sure :-) wish I could help